# How would you display all the items in an array list in one single line

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, output

How would you go about showing all the elements in an array list in one single line without having to show them on multiple lines. You would use a for loop to show each elememnt on each line but that is not what i am after.

Example ArrayList

```
ArrayList = {"Apple", "Banana", "Grape"}
```

Desired Output

```
"Apple Banana Grape"
```

NOT DESIRED OUTPUT

```
"Apple"
"Banana"
"Grape"
```

Comment: You can use `String.join` like this `println(String.join(" ",list))`

Comment: Use System.out.print(yourItem) and System.out.print(" ") for space between values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(list," ")`;

Answer (score 0):

You could create a string, and append those items to the string, then print the resulting string.

```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Grape"); 
  String fruitList = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i ){
    fruitList += list.get(i) + " ";
  }

    System.out.println(fruitList);
  }
```